# Get the text after the backslash in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone please help me to write a SQL query. I just need the first number after the first backslash "" Please see the desired output. Thank you

| ColumnName | Desire Output |
| --- | --- |
| \2610 | 2610 |
| \2610\1178_2018 Bake Inn | 2610 |
| \2610\1178_2018 Change Outlook\2018-03-12 AOR & Page 33 DL | 2610 |
| \995645\1178_2018 Creek Choc | 995645 |
| \995645\1178_2018 Record Request\Club & Volume 12 | 995645 |
| \995645 | 995645 |
| \4323234\54724_2020 Add Image\2021-2019 Details Open\Checkbox-06- Value | 4323234 |
| \4323234 | 4323234 |

Comment: the requirement of your question does not match the output (i.e. row 2 and 3). those cases you are stating show only the text after the first backslash

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on XQuery. Its data model is based on ordered sequences. Exactly what we need for the task. We can get to 1st token, 2nd token, last token, any token in a sequence right away.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('\2610'),
('\2610\1178_2018 Bake Inn'),
('\2610\1178_2018 Change Outlook\2018-03-12 AOR & Page 33 DL'),
('\995645\1178_2018 Creek Choc'),
('\995645\1178_2018 Record Request\Club & Volume 12'),
('\995645'),
('\4323234\54724_2020 Add Image\2021-2019 Details Open\Checkbox-06- Value'),
('\4323234');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, tokens
    , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [LeadingToken]
FROM @tbl
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, '\', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| ID |                                 tokens                                  | LeadingToken  |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|  1 | \2610                                                                   |          2610 |
|  2 | \2610\1178_2018 Bake Inn                                                |          2610 |
|  3 | \2610\1178_2018 Change Outlook\2018-03-12 AOR & Page 33 DL              |          2610 |
|  4 | \995645\1178_2018 Creek Choc                                            |        995645 |
|  5 | \995645\1178_2018 Record Request\Club & Volume 12                       |        995645 |
|  6 | \995645                                                                 |        995645 |
|  7 | \4323234\54724_2020 Add Image\2021-2019 Details Open\Checkbox-06- Value |       4323234 |
|  8 | \4323234                                                                |       4323234 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```